# String.valueOf(i) vs "" + i or i + ""

Tags: java, string, numbers, integer, numeric

I usually use `"" + i` for convenient. But compare about perfomance myself, I thought `String.valueOf(i)` will be faster. Is it right? Which one should I use?

Comment: Why don't you test for yourself? Or debug to see what "" + i actually calls. You'll be amazed ;)

Comment: `String.valueOf(i)` conveys the intent better imho. Anyways, if the bottleneck is really there, then you really have to refactor the code around

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut I don't know how to test the performance time. Can you give me what is the different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose what reads best. Then, profile your application before optimizing anything.

Always profile first (for instance with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) since you're coding in Java).

There are many resources on profiling and optimization. The latest good read I came across is this [Step by Step Optimisation by Tony Albrecht](http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/05/28/step_by_step_optimisation/).

And if performance really becomes critical, consider switching to [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

EDIT:

Well there is no straight answer to your question imho. Micro-benchmarking the performance of `String.valueOf(i)` against `i + ""` has little value. The real answer comes from benchmarking your application: its very own complexity and memory access pattern decides it all.

Those are not my ideas but I'm buying them: [stop programming like it's 1975](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectNotes), [big O notation needs an update](http://www.futurechips.org/thoughts-for-researchers/big-o-notation-useless-today.html).

Comment: Hey, it's an amazing answer! Not straight to my question, but it is how to solve my question!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to see any measurable difference. This seems to be what is usually referred to as micro (premature?) optimizations and are seldom a good idea.

Choose the method you and your fellow colleagues find easiest to read.

Comment: In case of millions recursive, the small difference will become big. So I need to know exactly.

Comment: @W.N. - that is incorrect.  You only need to know the answer **if** this is going to be executed millions of times **per second** ... **AND** your application **has to** run fast.  Profiling will give you an indication whether this tiny code fragment has a significant impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
Integer.toString( i )
```

if i is an integer as it might be possible for it to use an internal cache for better performance.

The difference would be small though

Comment: `String#valueOf(int) == Integer.toString(int)`

Comment: Would be an unnecessary hassle if he changes to `long` or some other type in the future though.

Comment: No internal cache. it is just a parsing. did you see the code?