# Primitive + "" versus Wrapper.toString(primitive)

Tags: java, coding-style

When needing to convert a primitive to a String, for example to pass to a method that expects a String, there are basically two options.

Using `int` as an example, given:

```
int i;
```

We can do one of:

```
someStringMethod(Integer.toString(i));
someStringMethod(i + "");
```

The first one is the "formal" approach, and the second one seems somewhat of a "hack".

It's certainly a lot less code and easier to read the "hack" IMHO.
But is it "good" coding style to use the "hack"?

Comment: I wouldn't describe the second version as easier to read.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130992/string-valueofi-vs-i-or-i?rq=1

Comment: I'll agree that the second is not really _easier to read_ and it certainly does not contain _at lot less code_.  Maybe fewer characters, but I can almost guarantee that it generates more bytecode.

Comment: @D.Shawley you are right, I remember that `""+something` generates something like `(new StringBuffer("")).append(String.valueOf(something).toString()` when decompiled, or some ugly stuff like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to convert * to String is to use:

```
String.valueOf(x)
```

it works with primitive types, wrapper classes and Object who do implement `toString()`.

where x is any kind of primitive or object. If it is null it returns the string 'null'.

The reason why this is best, is because using "+" operand implies String concatenation, plus the "" implies String instantiation. If you decompile a class using ""+something you'll see the compiler translate that to multiple operations.

"" concatenation result is the same as `String.valueOf()` but it is a little bit more expensive. 
The performance difference is probably negligible, but good programmers don't write '"" + something' to convert something to a String when there is a better way, which happens to be the correct way :).

For arrays, have a look at [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and -better- [Arrays.deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

> But is it "good" coding style to use the "hack"?

Sometimes syntactic hack make the code better. But the case above, is not really one of those cases. 
"" concatenation not considered good code.

An example of a useful syntactic hack is the double brace instantiation:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("foo");
    add("bar");
    add("baz");
}};
```

instead of

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
list.add("baz");
```

The ""+something is more a code smell than a hack that improve readability; anybody with some experience would think to a Java developer who lack some knowledge of the API and the language.

Other interesting "hacks" are fluent APIs (like Mockito), dsl, or things like lambda4j, which is quite an hack.

Comment: +1 - `valueOf` and similar operations should almost always be preferred over implicit coercion for precisely the `null` case.

Comment: I like String.valueOf(). Honestly I had forgotten about that

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea, but it's not going to be very harmful.

In both examples `Integer.toString()` is being called by the JVM (even if not directly in the first case).

In the second example, the JVM possibly constructs two strings and then produces the result of the concatenation. Depending on optimizations this may result in 0, 1 or 2 extra strings to garbage collect.

From a code writing perspective, the third is shorter, but also possibly less transparent as to what is happening.

The problems with the second approach in readability follow:

```
int i = 1, j = 2;
someStringMethod(i + j + "" + i + j + "");
```

Produces:

```
someStringMethod(312);
```

and not

```
someStringMethod(33);
```

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that `Integer.toString()` is being called in both cases.  `javap` shows that the appender method calls `StringBuilder.append` twice - once with an integer argument and a string argument.  Most modern Java implementations stopped using string concatenation quite some time ago.

Comment: We're talking about programming style here, not efficiency. The concatenation almost certainly will be optimized away by the compiler. In any case, you'd have to profile your code to find out if it really makes a difference. But by all means, use .toString, or a StringBuilder, for style reasons.

Comment: I put an example of cases where it can become unclear due to the multiple uses of the + operator. Honestly though, CheckStyle doesn't moan about either method so it's not a big deal...

Thanks for the correction @D.Shawley

Answer (score 1):

When strings are formed using + sign, jvm will create a intermediate string/stringbuffer object to carry out trasnformation, which is not the optimum way.
Also, + sign is left associative,so when used in expressions like  *""+1+2* will result in 12 and not  "3".So it's better to use  String.toValue() or  Type.toString().

Comment: actually it's `String.valueOf()` not `String.toValue()`, but your answer is correct. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation symbol in java is +. 
So you convert the result of  `(i + "")` to String because you concat an empty string to a number in your example code.
The two ways are good but I normally use `String.valueOf(x);`